# What is the difference between using replace all and using the value of a function?

Tags: functions, replacement

For a project I'm working on, I'm using some functions that have a `Chop[]` to get rid of small terms that complicate things numerically. My function is `heq[t_]:=Chop[...]`. For example, when I input `heq[1000]`, I get `heq[1000] = 0.35P1[1000] + 0.99P2[1000]`. However, if I input `heq[t]/.t->1000`, I get `heq[t]/.t->1000 = 0.35P1[1000] + 0.99P2[1000] + 1.23*10^(-81)P3[1000]`. Basically, the second format does not execute the `Chop` of the small numbers. Sorry if the answer is obvious, it's my first year using Mathematica and I couldn't get a clear answer from the documentation. If anybody can help me I would appreciate it and thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I'm guessing it's simply a matter of order of evaluation. In `f[t] /. rules`, `f[t]` is evaluated first, then `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) acts. What happens if you evaluate `heq[t]` by itself?

Comment: (there are various easy ways to prevent this! but first i want to make sure it's actually what's going on.)

Comment: as an example, if this is what's going on: consider `Chop[t]`. The result is just `t`, since there are no numerics to chop. So `Chop[t] /. t -> 1.*^-18` ⇒ `t /. t -> 1.*^-18` ⇒ `1.*^-18`, whereas `Chop[1.*^-18]` ⇒ `0`.

Comment: If the function uses `Chop` it probably shouldn't evaluate unless it has a numeric argument. Ensure this with something like `f[x_?NumericQ] := definition`